# Match an element inside nested array

Tags: r, nested

I have a list which has the following structure.

```
data
|
|
-> entities
   |
   -> 0
   |
   -> 1
   |
   -> 2
```

- Each entities element contains some elements like name, type, age

**Problem:**

I want to find the name and age of entity such that entity[[x]]$type == 'applicant'

**Current Solution:**

Currently I was think of creating lists for each element and thus trying to filter by type but this is not a long term solution

```
entity_one <- data.frame(data$entity[[1]]$name, data$entity[[1]]$type, data$entity[[1]]$age)
```

Comment: Can you please paste some example data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use:

```
data$entity[lapply(data$entity, '[[', 'type') == 'applicant']
```